# How to use instagram API on different websites

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

My company has different websites for different customers, each of them using instagram API to retrieve pictures from customer's instagram account.

I have tried to register different instagram clients but it has been rejected because 'We don't approve multiple submissions for the same company. Please consolidate all your integrations under a single client_id.'

How one would solve this problem ? An instagram client has its own website url, privacy policy url and redirect_url which obviously can't be shared between different websites.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to get your client approved to "go live"... does it meet one of their only three acceptable use cases (since June 1st 2016)?

- “My app allows people to login with Instagram and share their own
  content”
- “My product helps brands and advertisers understand, manage
  their audience and media rights.”
- “My product helps broadcasters and
  publishers discover content, get digital rights to media, and share
  media with proper attribution.”

If your use case doesn't fit their new agenda you will never get it approved to go live no matter how consolidated it is. Your only other option is to stay in Sandbox mode. First read about [the limitations of Sandbox mode](https://medium.com/@emersonthis/instagram-on-websites-the-new-landscape-62c91d733894#.4z8g35g2s) and if these are acceptable, then you don't have to worry about submission process at all. Just create multiple API clients and leave them in Sandbox mode forever. But if you're doing anything besides showing a few recent photos on your customer's sites, Sandbox mode probably won't cut it for you and you may be out of luck.

Comment: Sandbox mode is only useful when in development mode (max 10 users for example). One of my websites has already been approved, so it respects Instagram wills. I can't believe this basic usage of having different websites owned by the same company using Instagram is impossible.

Comment: Sandbox Mode IS development mode. They are the same thing... and you're absolutely right that it is really frustrating. It was deliberately set up to quash 3rd party development. If one of your clients is already approved, can you add additional redirect URIs without a new submission?